# I live in Alabama. Extremely humid and hot climate. Advice for replacing roof?

Tags: roof

My house is over 50 years old.  I live in Alabama, where temps normally exceed 100°F in July/August each year.

I have the original 3/8" 24" on Center roof decking.  For at least 42 years, there were no soffit vents in this house, but probably a good bit of shade.  Before I put in a power vent and lots of soffits, vent temps would often reach 140-150°F for much of the day.

I have to replace my shingles. The question is should I completely tear off the old 3/8" deck and replace it with? 19/32" OSB? Just replace any obviously bad sheets with 7/16 OSB?  Age old dilemma.

I don't know yet what kind of price I'm going to have for the labor to completely tear off the old and install the new if I choose to do that. Also there is the option to install 7/16 on top of the old 3/8, replacing any bad 3/8 first. They do it around here at least sometimes.  Any advice on which is better?

Comment: The other question is: I have one of those White aluminum patio covers that are a terrible design but I'm stuck with it and need it to collect water and divert into drain pipes due to flooding problems. What is the best way to seal the transition from the roof deck to that aluminum awning? Is some type of self adhering underlayment a good idea? combine it with galvanized flashing?

Comment: Usually best to make a new question, especially for different matter/section.  Probably be nicer to have a thicker roof deck.  Unless the 3/8 is in bad condition would just add on top, instead of removing.

Comment: Why do you suspect the roof cladding is damaged?

Comment: the decking feels weak to me and doesn't look great from the attic. It's been exposed to extreme heat and humidity for so long, I"m just concerned about. I get a different opinion from each roofer and even a different opinion from the same roofer depending on when you ask them! No rhyme or reason or science behind their decision making

Comment: I've had my roof replaced twice. Each time I knew there were some small leaks and problems. Each time the estimate was always "plus $x per sheet of plywood *as needed*". Each time I was pleasantly surprised at how little needed to be replaced. Admittedly, Maryland is not as harsh a climate, but plenty of cold/ice/snow in the winter and heat/humidity in the summer. My hunch is your roofers are all just guessing because until they strip off the shingles they really don't know.

Comment: yeah, it seems to be a guessing game. thanks

Comment: And some may "guess" low ("oh yeah, it will all be fine, minor repairs, no big deal") because they want the business, and others high ("probably have to replace most of the deck after all these years") because they don't want the business so much but will take it if it is profitable enough (which it will be if they pad it with enough other stuff). And the same contractor might flip-flop depending on factors beyond your control.

Comment: *"decking feels weak to me"* - 3/8" on 24" centers? Um, yeah I bet it does. - Sign whoever *refuses* to quote you *w/o* "plus $x per sheet of plywood as needed" *as well as* "7/16 on top of the old 3/8, replacing any bad 3/8 first." because *they're all just guessing*, but there's no math involved with that thickness at that span being crap even though it meets code.

Comment: 3/8 is not something I would be happy to be jumping on, but no snow load and careful walking, probably okay, just.

Answer (score 1):

The 3/8" astounds me--even at 16" o.c... That being said, one option you might consider which would increase the strength and reduce the weight load at the same time: metal roofing. I too live in AL and LOVE my standing seam metal roof. If you choose this option ensure that the existing asphalt roof is completely removed. Standing-seam however is not cheap.

Comment: thank you.  One impediment to that is I already bought my shingle materials. Home depot might take them back but I'm not sure. Do you know what standing simple costs per square on a very simple single ridge, 4/12 pitch roof?

Comment: @scott: I am sure HD will accept a return if they are unopen/not damaged. As to the cost of standing seam metal, when I had mine done 12 yrs ago the estimates varied from 22K to 50K for my complex roof of ~45 sq. I'm guessing you'd be lucky to get it for $1K/sq now--but that is a very wild guess. If you are in N Ala I can give you my guys name/number.

Answer (score 1):

First, it's best to remove existing roofing materials before installing a new roof.  You can usually get away with 1 new roof over an old roof, but over-roofing 2 is really too many.  I doubt your original shingle roof is 50 years old.

Replacing OSB is a judgment call based on the conditions found.  Budget for it all, but don't be surprised if frequent trips to the lumberyard are needed as the degree of damage is discovered (or lack of damage).

You do not want an uneven roof surface, and you do not want to extensively sand to smooth joints.  3/8" OSB seems awfully darn light to me, unless there was a metal roof on top of it.   Hey, don't you have hurricanes there?

Metal roofs are fantastic. Don't get all hung up in "standing seam roof" - that's just an uber-fancy metal roof.  Good ole "Tin roof, rusted" will outperform shingles any day, and will add structural strength to make up for the OSB.  And, the "tin roof" can be renewed by power wirebrushing away any rust, and painting with Cold Galvanizing Compound (basically paint, but the resin is 90% zinc).  Sold at McMaster-Carr.

Tin roof can also be painted, if allowed to age for a year to give the zinc time to oxidize (better surface for primer to bind to).

**Speaking of that ... how is your air conditioning bill?**  The #1 reason you need air conditioning is called **Solar Gain**. Every square foot of surface facing the sun gets 100 watts of heat (that's 340 BTU/hr). That's assuming it has a reflectivity (albedo) of zero.  Which is about right for a shingle roof LOL.  On the other hand, if the roof is white.... my paint supplier tells me "Snow White" paint has reflectivity of 91% - so 1 square foot only gets 9 watts or about 30 BTU/hr of heat coming onto it.

Seriously, solar gain is *the lion's share* of your A/C load. If you had the exact same house fully shaded, you'd have a tiny fraction of the A/C bill.

A white roof gives you *much* of this effect, by reflecting most solar gain right back into the atmosphere (and some of it goes back into space, actually).

Take a 2000 square foot roof, say it's angled to the sun so it's presenting 1000 square feet square on, that's - gosh - 340,000 BTU/hr of solar gain on that roof. Some of that is stopped by the insulation, but still that's a considerable part of your total A/C load.  Paint it white and 340,000 becomes 30,000 BTU/hr, with the insulation having *better* blocking power, because the roof is less hot.

Comment: I agree with alot of what you say. I tried explaining this concept to the roofer re: Radiant decking. Only one knew what I was talking about. One roofer said metal expands and contracts and the screws come loose. Not sure if that included metal roofs with metal purlins installed first over the decking. My situation is complicated by the need to get this done soon and to have gutters draining into a drain system. I was hit by two tornadoes and some flooding. Plus I've been sick and still am. To top it off, I have one of those aluminum patio covers that leak a little. That is running off roofers

Comment: and yes my attic gets very hot. I may staple some radiant barrier in the attic. I tried and tried to get the "cool" shingles but guess what? not available in this super hot climate where they are very much needed, SMH

Comment: @Scott If you'd prefer a specialty roof, you'll need to reach out farther to find specialists good at that roof.  Of course the local town roofers will only do the one thing well: shingles.  But shingles require replacing ALL your OSB, and metal doesn't, so advantage: metal. If they're dissing a roof, that means THEY shouldn't be installing it.  Unfortunately, "radiant barrier" inside the attic does next to nothing and is mostly a scam.  The only place reflection works is on the top of the roof, once it's heating up your roof, only the insulation slows it down.

Comment: I put on a new white roof last year. I also put in ridge vents and added a lot of soffit vents.  The electric bill went down a lot because of the reduced AC load. The attic is about 30 degrees cooler. I would suggest replacing with white, material is what your budget can adsorb.  This is in Michigan and yes we approached 100 already this year.